# How to get Pet Toys in Harvest Moon: Tale of Two Towns

Tags: harvest-moon-two-towns

My girlfriend is playing Harvest Moon DS in my DS and she doesn't know how to get toys for their pets to play with.

Does anyone know how to get/buy the pet toys?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the Dog Bone or the Cat Bell, have you checked Diego or Raul's shop?  They should start stocking the appropriate item the day after you get your pet.